# How do I decide or count number of hidden/tunable parameters in my design?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning

For my deep learning assignment I need to design a image classification network. There this constraint in the assignment I can have 500,000 number of hidden/tunable parameters at most in this design.

How can I count or observe the number of these hidden parameters especially if I am using [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/) tensor flow tutorial as initial code/design.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> How can I count or observe the number of these hidden parameters especially if I am using [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/) tensor flow tutorial as initial code/design.

- Instead of me doing the work for you I'll show you how to count free parameters

Glancing quickly it looks like the code at [cifar10](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/) uses layers of **max pooling, convolution, bias, fully connected weights**.  Let's review how many free parameters each of these layers adds to your architecture.

- **max pooling** : FREE!  That's right, there are no "free parameters" from max pooling.
- **conv** : Convolutions are defined using parameters like [1,3,3,1] where the numbers correspond to your tensor like so [batch_size, CONV_SIZE, CONV_SIZE, FEATURE_DEPTH].  Multiply all the dimension sizes together to find the total size of your free parameters.  In the case of [1,3,3,1], the total is 1x3x3x1 = 9.
- **bias** : A Bias is similar to convolutions in that it is defined by a shape like [10] or [1,342,342,3].  Same thing, just multiply all dimension sizes together to get the total free parameters.  Sometimes a bias is just a single number, which means a size of **1**.
- **fully connected** : A fully connected layer usually has a 2d shape like [1024,32].  This means that it is a 2d matrix, and you calculate the total free parameters just like the convolution.  In this example [1024,32] has 1024x32 = 32,768 free parameters.

Finally you add up all the free parameters from all the layers and that is your total number of free parameters.

Comment: Hi @bakayim , if this answers your question then please accept is as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

500 000 parmeters? You use an R, G and B value of each pixel? If yes there is some problems
1. too much data (long calculating time)
2. in image clasification companys always use some other image analysis technique(preprocesing) befor throwing data into NN. if you have to identical images. Second is moved by one piksel. For the network they can be very diffrend.
Imagine other neural network. Use two parameters maybe weight and height. If you swap this parametrs what will happend.
Yes during learning of your image network can decrease this effect but when I made experiments with 5x5 binary images that was very hard to network. I start using 4 layers but this help only a little.
The image used to lerning can be good clasified, after destoring also but mooving for one pixel and you have a problem.
If no make eksperiments or use genetic algoritm to find it.
After laerning you should use some algoritm to find dates with network recognize as "no important"(big differnce beetwen weight of this input and the rest, If this input weight are too close to 0 network "think" it is no important)